# i18next with react-native custom language detector not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, i18next, asyncstorage, react-i18next

I am using i18next with a custom language detector to detect language from async-storage but it looks like detect method is not even called and every time fallbackLanguage = 'en' is chosen.

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import en from './languages/english.json';
import hi from './languages/hindi.json';
import kn from './languages/kannada.json';
import ta from './languages/tamil.json';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const resources = {
  en: en,
  hi: hi,
  kn: kn,
  ta: ta,
};

let fallbackLanguage = 'en';

const languageDetector = {
  type: 'languageDetector',
  async: true,
  detect: async (callback) => 
    try {
      const language = await AsyncStorage.getItem('language');
      console.log('lllanguage', language);
      if (language) {
        console.log('Detected language:', language);
        callback(language);
      } else {
        console.log('No language detected, falling back to default language:', fallbackLanguage);
        callback(fallbackLanguage);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to get language from async storage:', error);
      callback(fallbackLanguage);
    }
  },
  fallbackLng: fallbackLanguage,
};


i18n
  .use(languageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
    lng: fallbackLanguage,
    resources,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

the localstorage has item 'language' and is setting the value as expected and i want everytime i open the app it detects language from async-storage and does not lose its state on closing.

Answer (score 0):

```
const languageDetector = {
  type: 'languageDetector',
  async: true,
  detect: async (callback) => {
    console.log("arrived here")
    try {
      const language = await AsyncStorage.getItem('language');
      console.log('lllanguage', language);
      if (language) {
        console.log('Detected language:', language);
        callback(language);
      } else {
        console.log('No language detected, falling back to default language:', fallbackLanguage);
        callback(fallbackLanguage);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to get language from async storage:', error);
      callback(fallbackLanguage);
    }
  },
  init: () => {
    console.log('init');
  },
  fallbackLng: fallbackLanguage,
};
```

update your code with this to check if init is printing or not this will be just a check to know if languageDetector is executing or not

Comment: its logging 'init'. can i get a little more help ?